# JS browser extension to console log words

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a browser extension which I eventually will turn into a translator but for its current purpose I just want my extension to console log the word that is clicked on the page. I am using vanilla JS for this part:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', checkWord);

function checkWord() {
    console.log('the word is')
    let word = window.getSelection().toString();
    console.log(word);
}
```

If I remove the `.toString()` method the program will return the entire object to the console. However with the `.toString()` method the console log gives me an empty return.  Should I be using a different method to extract the actual word clicked on?

Comment: So what is the question? `window.getSelection()` indeed returns an object

Comment: Sorry, @falinsky I forgot to mention that with the .toString I am getting a blank console log.

Comment: Simply clicking on something won't select it, so maybe that's why you're getting an empty string. Try actually selecting something and then call toString()